# Multifield validation with summary and fields highlighted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm in asp.net MVC and I'm trying to create a custom ValidationAttribute that targets my model class to enforce that a group of fields are either empty or all filled. If it's not valid, I want it to return a validation summary at the top of the form and highlight all of the required fields red with no validation message on the fields themselves... Here is my code now...

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class CourtSearchNameDOBValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var searchData = (CourtSearchModel)value;

        if(validationContext == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var firstNameIsEmpty = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchData.FirstName);
        var lastNameIsEmpty = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchData.LastName);
        var dateOfBirthIsEmpty = searchData.DateOfBirth == null;

        var allFieldsAreEmpty = firstNameIsEmpty && lastNameIsEmpty && dateOfBirthIsEmpty ;

        // All fields must be filled in if any are filled
        if (!allFieldsAreEmpty)
        {
            if (firstNameIsEmpty || lastNameIsEmpty || dateOfBirthIsEmpty)
            {
                var validationResults = new ValidationResult("All name fields are required", new List<string>() { "FirstName", "LastName", "DateOfBirth" });
                return validationResults;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Right now, only my FirstName property is highlighted and the error message "All name fields are required" is on that field (which this part is expected). What I'm not expecting and am confused about is the part where the other fields (LastName and DateOfBirth) are not also high lighted and displaying a validation message. I included them in the memberNames property of the ValidationResult...

Comment: you can use Fluentvalidation  -> https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation